# How do I use JOptionPane in an If statement?

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am new to learning Java. In an assignment, I am using If/Else statements and trying to display information in JOptionPane. Here is a quick example I made to show the issue I'm having. I want to display "Hello there" if the input in the string hello is equal to "hey".

Nothing comes up.

I noticed that if I put the JOptionPane statement earlier in the code, such as next to the scanner declaration, it will work. Also, if I do that AND leave the other JOptionPane in the original location, there will be TWO dialog boxes.

I was thinking that maybe the scanner input is messing with it somehow.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW2 {
    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Say hey");
        String hello = kb.nextLine();
        if (hello.equals("hey")) 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello there!");
        kb.close();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why the dialog box isn't showing up? Thanks!

Comment: `"hi"` != `"hey"`

Comment: Q: Does anything show up if your entire "main()" is the single line `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello there!");`?  Q: Are you sure nextLine is returning *exactly* what you're checking for?  For example, have you considered using `String.startsWith()` instead?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say  I want to display "Hello there" if the input in the string hello is equal to "hey".

Comment: I ran your code, entered "hey" at the prompt and it works fine for me. As a side note, you shouldn't be closing the `Scanner`, as this will also close the system in stream, which you really don't want to do

Comment: @paulsm4 I think so? I tried inserting `System.out.print(hello);` to see if it would display "hey" and it did. In what way should I use `String.startsWith()` ? Sorry, very new to this.

Comment: @vs97 So the dialog box came up? That is strange because it is not for me. But I am able to make it come up by moving the JOptionPane statement somewhere else so I don't think there's an issue of the pane being hidden.

Comment: Try this: `System.out.print(">>" + hello + "<<")`.  The idea is to see if maybe your string includes a newline or something else "unexpected".  Q: How do you use "startsWith()"?  Easy: `if (hello.startsWith("hey") {...}`.  The mitigates the situtation if your string happens to be "hey\n" ("hey", with a newline character at the end).

Comment: @paulsm4 I understand that you're trying to eliminate possible trap doors, but Scanner has a defined behaviour and adding `\n` isn't one of them. If OP really writes "hey" into the console, then "hey" will be assigned to the String `hello`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you don't really have any problem here, simply your JOptionPane is hidden behind your IDE window or is somewhere in the back. In order to always bring it to front, try using something like this:

```
if (hello.equals("hey")) {
     JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane();
     JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog("My Test");
     pane.setMessage("Hello There");
     dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
     dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

This will give you a bit more flexibility in where you want to make it visible. Another way a bit shorter, but same idea:

```
if (hello.equals("hey")) {
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, "Hello There");
}
```

Complete code for you to play around with:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Say hey");
        String hello = kb.nextLine(); //use kb.nextLine().trim() if you dont want whitespaces
        if (hello.equals("hey")) {
            JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
            dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, "Hello There");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but there was an error with JDialog saying "JDialog cannot be resolved to a type." Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @court0 added entire code for you to try, just copy and paste and should work

Comment: @court0 Sounds like you're missing the import for JDialog.

Comment: @vs97 Okay, yes that works thank you! But does that mean I would always have to include that code, even if I have a bunch of `else if` statements, just for the dialog box to show up on top?

Comment: @court0 not necessarily, you can extract that code into a separate method and give the dialog message as a parameter String if you need the message to be different. If you don't, then no need for any parameter, just extract.